# HTML form not does not open client because of too many input fields?

Tags: html, cgi, forms

Constants for both problems: using the action="mailto:emailme@hello.com", browsers used-IE and Chrome, html form built to have 117 field inputs (I know, its a lot.)

1. Problem #1

   - html form **will not** invoke the email client if I have too many input fields (117) while using the `method="Post"` or `method="POST"`.    Result - When clicking submit button, the button appears as if clicked but the email client is not invoked
   - If I decrease input fields on the html page from 117 to 94, and use either `method="Post"` or `method="POST"`. Result - When clicking submit button, client email opens and 94 field inputs appear. Almost a success, but I am missing 23 input fields
2. Problem # 2

   - html form **will** invoke the email client even though I have 117 input fields, while using `method="Get"`. Result - Email client opens but input field entries are not added to the email--the email body is blank

Can someone offer suggestions based on my explanation above? Or, please take a look at my code to see if I a doing something wrong?

Thank you.

The html is too long to list, so [I've place the code here](https://sites.google.com/site/testingcodework/home).

Comment: This sounds like a ridiculously inefficient way to do something that's been done for years.  Why wouldn't you just use a POST method that links to a PHP (or other server side language) form mail script?

Comment: Scripting might be the end goal. But, when you work for a government agency and you have to go through the many layers to talk to web admin to get access to the server, you use works-around. My effort is a work around.

Comment: As I understand it, `mailto:...` causes the browser to open an external mail application. So, that means that you may be dealing with a limitation of the external mail application that you are using, which is not mentioned here.